# Cannot mount Android microSD after crash

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, usb, data-recovery

I took the microSD out of my Samsung S8+ to copy all the images to my Windows computer.  There was an error during copying and the system ended up freezing then BSOD.  Did a hard restart, put the SD card back into the system and BSOD again.  So I moved the microSD back to my S8 and it didn't recognize it and could not mount it.  I took it back out and plugged it into a Linux system.  It would not mount or even show up in various listings (df, lsusb, etc).  I can see that there is activity on the device (as seen in the outputs below) but that's about it.

I'd like to be able to recover the data on the microSD but not sure how to do that if I can't even get Windows or Linux to recognize the drive for it to mount.  It looks like as soon as it attaches as a SCSI removable device, the USB disconnects.  Is there a way to prevent the USB disconnection from occurring?  I don't know if that would then allow me raw access to the device.  Any other suggestions?

```
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.452404] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.604205] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0177
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.604214] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.604220] usb 1-5: Product: USB2.0-CRW
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.604226] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Generic
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.604232] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 20121112761000000
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.608785] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 kernel: [ 1591.609245] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 24: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5"
May  2 15:19:23 Debian1 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 24 was not an MTP device
May  2 15:19:24 Debian1 kernel: [ 1592.630328] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC/MS PRO    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
May  2 15:19:24 Debian1 kernel: [ 1592.631477] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
May  2 15:19:30 Debian1 kernel: [ 1598.800616] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May  2 15:19:34 Debian1 kernel: [ 1602.629018] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 24
```

udevadm monitor output

```
KERNEL[1591.581216] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5 (usb)
KERNEL[1591.584994] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1591.585652] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2 (scsi)
KERNEL[1591.585735] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [1591.605139] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5 (usb)
UDEV  [1591.606692] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1591.607810] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2 (scsi)
UDEV  [1591.610094] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[1592.607141] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[1592.607277] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[1592.607386] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[1592.607458] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[1592.607645] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[1592.607809] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [1592.610899] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1592.613339] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1592.614373] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [1592.614978] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [1592.615350] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [1592.615377] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[1595.692241] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[1595.692643] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [1595.695889] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[1602.605813] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[1602.606025] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[1602.606091] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[1602.606371] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [1602.609689] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/bsg/2:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [1602.612086] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [1602.612591] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_device/2:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [1602.612652] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[1602.624207] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[1602.624540] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[1602.624599] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[1602.664726] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[1602.664832] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1602.665772] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[1602.720990] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[1602.721108] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2 (scsi)
KERNEL[1602.721407] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1602.722117] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5 (usb)
UDEV  [1602.722866] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/scsi_host/host2 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [1602.893625] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [1602.900979] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [1602.903028] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [1602.903891] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1602.905108] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2/target2:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1602.906302] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host2 (scsi)
UDEV  [1602.907551] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1602.912791] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5 (usb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recover your data with the tool called testdisk, but make sure to read the documentation before you use it, because it may break your other drives if you do something wrong.